# R scatterplot matrix: Adjust x- and y-axis limits of each plot in a scatterplot matrix

Tags: r, matrix, axis, scatter-plot, yaxis

How to adjust x- and y-axis limits of each plot in a **scatterplot matrix** created using R programming (for e.g. I want to force each plot's y-axis to start at 0)? Below is my code that uses pairs function and adds a y=x line in each plot. If you have an alternative way to include y=x line in each plot, please share your thoughts on that. Thank you for your help.

```
library(car)

All_combined <- read.csv("C:/Users/johnwac/Documents/Modes_Combined.csv", header=T, sep=",")

mat1=subset(All_combined,select=c("Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4"))

oneline = function(x,y) {
    points(x,y,pch=".")
    abline(lsfit(x,x), col="blue")
    }

pairs(mat1,panel=oneline, main="Title of plot")
```

Comment: In the `pairs` function, you can set the limits for all plots using `xlim=` and `ylim=`, but you cannot set just the lower limit or just the upper limit and you cannot set different limits for different plots.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You are more likely to get better answers if you provide a [mcve] so other users can replicate your situation. Please also see [ask].

Comment: I added my code block in the question. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Any thought on my question?